# Laravel Database MySQL Queries take very long

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a page that connects to my database, but it takes about 1 minute for the page to load after collecting all the data.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is there something I can do to speed this process up?

Controller

```
class ReportSummaryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (@$user->name)
            $details = DB::table('taffiliate')
                ->where('affID', "=", $user->name)
                ->get();
        else
            return redirect('/login');

        view()->share('details', $details);
    }

    public function index()
    {


        $user = Auth::user();
        $affiliate = $user->name;


        $affdata = DB::table('toutcome')->select(DB::raw('sum(LenderCommission) as LenderCommission'), 'AffID', 'AppID')
            ->whereRaw('CompletedDate >= curdate()')
            ->groupBy('AffID')
            ->orderBy('AppID', 'ASC')
            ->get();



        $data3 = DB::table('toutcome')

            ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
            ->whereRaw('AffID Not Like "MW0050"')

            ->join('tapplicant', 'toutcome.AppID', '=', 'tapplicant.AppID')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(CompletedDate, "%d %M %Y") as CompletedDate, 
                              SUM(LenderCommission) as commission, 
                              SUM(AffCommission) as affCommission,
                              COUNT(DISTINCT tapplicant.Email) as leadcount,
                              SUM(Status = "A" AND LenderCommission Not Like "0.00") as acceptcount'))

            ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(CompletedDate, "%d %M %Y")'))
            ->get();



        $users = Toutcome::where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())

            ->join('tapplicant', 'toutcome.AppID', '=', 'tapplicant.AppID')
        ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(CompletedDate, "%d %M %Y") as CompletedDate, 
                              SUM(LenderCommission) as Commission, 
                              SUM(AffCommission) as Affiliate_Commission, 
                              COUNT(DISTINCT tapplicant.Email) as Applications,
                              SUM(Status = "A" AND LenderCommission Not Like "0.00") as Sold'))
            ->whereRaw('AffID Not Like "MW0050"')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(CompletedDate, "%d %M %Y")'))
            ->get();

$comtotal = DB::table('toutcome')

    ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
    ->whereRaw('LenderCommission Not Like "0.00"')

    ->sum('LenderCommission');

        $subid = DB::table('tapplicant')
            ->whereRaw('AppAffID Not Like "050"')
            ->whereRaw('AppAffID Not Like "000"')
            ->where('AppDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
            ->select('AppAffID')
            ->groupBy('AppAffID')
            ->get();

        $lender = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->select('LenderName')
            ->groupBy('LenderName')
            ->get();

        $imtotal = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
            ->whereRaw('LenderCommission Not Like "0.00"')
            ->whereRaw('AffID Not Like "0050"')
            ->count('AppID');

        $cototal = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
            ->whereRaw('LenderCommission Not Like "0.00"')
            ->whereRaw('AffID Not Like "0050"')
            ->where('Status', '=', 'A')
            ->count('AppID');

        $comtotal2 = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
            ->whereRaw('LenderCommission Not Like "0.00"')
            ->sum('LenderCommission');

        $comtotal3 = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
            ->whereRaw('LenderCommission Not Like "0.00"')
            ->sum('AffCommission');

return view('summary', compact('affdata','data3', 'comtotal', 'subid' , 'users', 'lender', 'imtotal', 'cototal', 'comtotal2', 'comtotal3'));



    }
```

Comment: Well you are shooting heavy commands into your DB like a machinegun. If there's a couple of thousand rows in your DB, operations like these just are going to use a lot time. You can try upping the memory of your DB or transferring to another, quicker server entirely. I don't know enough about MySQL to help you with optimizing these queries, but I know enough to know this kind of stuff is just going to take a long time on an average server.

Comment: Omg. I've never seen much query like this before..

Comment: @Loek , i know .... and i have about 350 000 records. My tables have about 15 fields each as well.

Comment: Maybe move or ask to move your post to the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, they might be able to help out on improving calls and/or queries.

Comment: @JhonnyWalker , thanks i did that : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139038/laravel-database-mysql-queries-take-very-long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly that sounds really long.

The queries do look quite detailed, but it shouldn't take longer than 1 minute.

You could try using eloquent, but this will be only a little quicker than the raw queries.

Things you didn't mention are :

Is this a local server or remote server ?
If you are using a remote server, my solution would be to use the **"skip-name-resolve"** in your my.ini / my.cnf under mysqld and update your key_buffer_size.

If this does not improve the speed, maybe look at your resources for that particular server.

Comment: I updated my key_buffer_size and added skip_name_resolve. i had to restart mysql server though. This worked 100 percent , thanks @MatHatrik

Comment: Thanks both of you. You've saved my many hours.